# HAProxy stops proxying traffic, but doesn't crash or log

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, haproxy

I have a long running HAProxy server that's proxying requests to 100+ applications and microservices.  It's running on Ubuntu 16.04 and the output of haproxy -v is:

> HA-Proxy version 1.6.3 2015/12/25

In the last few months, HAProxy will occassionally (between 15 minutes and 5 hours between instances) just stop forwarding traffic.  All the applications and microservices behind the proxy won't connect.

When this occurs the HAProxy service (sudo systemctl status haproxy) says that it's still active, so it hasn't crashed.

All the other places I know to look have no recent log entries:

> sudo journalctl -u haproxy

> less /var/log/haproxy.log

> less /var/log/syslog

> dmesg -T

So I guess my question is twofold.

1. Has anyone seen anything like this before?
2. Is there anywhere to look that I'm not already looking, or configuration changes I can make to log potentially helpful information?